# Structuring a Database That Counts Similar Entries

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I'm new to databases. I'm organizing music using `mysqlite3`. I have `ArtistName`, `SongTitle`, and `AlbumTitle` fields in the `Music` table. The primary purpose of the database is to query it and return all of the artists who have less than 3 songs.

To achieve this, I think I will need some kind of "song count" entry that increments every time I add a song from the same artist. However, I'm not sure how to create a dynamic entry. I know of the AUTO_INCREMENT keyword, which has the dynamic properties I'm looking for, but not the conditional incrementing.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something in your request you do not need a `songCount` column, you can easily get the artists that have less than 3 songs but using the following query:

```
select artistname
from music
group by artistname
having count(SongTitle) <3
```

This will return the `artistname` for every artist that has count of songs less than three total songs.

Then if you want to expand on this, you can use the following which will return all of the columns from the `music` table where the artist has less than 3 songs:

```
select m1.*
from music m1
where exists (select artistname
              from music m2
              where m1.artistname = m2.artistname
              group by artistname
              having count(SongTitle) <3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "count" field. Try this...

```
SELECT ArtistName
FROM Music
GROUP BY ArtistName
HAVING Count(ArtistName) < 3
```

This is assuming there is only one entry for each song.